# How to generate mocha test case report and show using Jenkins?

Tags: testing, jenkins, mocha.js

I am doing mocha unit testing for my JavaScript functions. I am running mocha in a browser not using Node. I am using require.js to load files.

When I do mocha.run() it shows reports in the browser.

Now I want to make a Jenkins job to display the report.

So how do I generate the report file so that I can provide it to Jenkins?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue! Do you have any update? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Run the command

```
$ mocha ./test.js --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options ./test-results.xml
```

For docker file use below command

```
CMD ["mocha", "./test.js" , "--reporter", "mocha-junit-reporter", "--reporter-options","./test-results.xml"]
```

Both command will do the same.
test-results.xml file be generate in the folder .

Answer (score 2):

Running the command:

```
$ npm install mocha-junit-reporter --save-dev
```

Will generate an XML file that you can give to Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question, I have solve this problem by using NGINX server which is open source.
I have added form tag in index.html of mocha and wrote on function on submit form to run mocha suit, this will return you output , parse that output and make file of that according to your need like total success count, failure count etc. and gave to Jenkins.